# How to implement file browser like android in Xamarin forms IOS

Tags: file-upload, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, filepicker, uidocumentpickervc

Currently I am using File picker plugin(https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows) to browse and attach files in my application.
Its an cross platform plugin to upload documents.

but in this plugin when we want to upload documents in IOS we can upload documents using ICloud only. I want to upload documents without Icloud as we are doing in android.

[image]

Can anyone help me to upload documents in Xamarin forms IOS without using ICloud?

Comment: What you've tried??

Comment: Currently I am using file picker, but was unable to find any way to browse files as we are doing in android

Comment: Finally I found answer that we cannot do it in IOS, but IOS is providing this feature from IOS 11

Comment: @mauliksakhare Did you get the answer

Comment: @AswathyKR no we cannot do this in IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to browse files like android in iOS

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. In iOS 11 it is possible.